# How do I turn off sound effects?

Tags: ios, sound-volume

iOS emits a variety of unnecessary sound effects in response to user interaction, e.g.:

- Connect a power source.
- Take a photo.
- Capture a screenshot.
- Authorize an App Store purchase.

How do I disable them?

What I’ve tried:

- Since every other operating system I’ve used has a simple setting for this—

  - macOS: *System Preferences → Sound → Play user interface sound effects*
  - Windows: *Control Panel → Sound → Sounds → No Sounds*
  - Ubuntu: *System Settings → Sound → Sound Effects → Mute*
  - Android: *Settings → Sound → Other sounds → …*

  —I expected that iOS would have one too. I looked around in *Settings → Sounds & Haptics* but couldn’t find it.
- Physically switching the iPhone’s ring/silent switch to silent does successfully mute sound effects, but this has the undesirable side effect of stopping my phone from ringing.

  I have no problem with the phone making noise when it needs my attention; it’s the redundant, often skeuomorphic sounds that I’m asking about disabling.

Comment: Which other sound effects?

Comment: If iPhone: Have you tried using the “silent button”? (It’s the one above the volume buttons)

Comment: Yes, that resulted in collateral damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I conclude that this is not possible in iOS.